# How to upload the certificate for Client TLS option's after the destination was created

Tags: ibm-cloud, secure-gateway

I would like to change a Bluemix Secure Gateway destination's Client TLS option enabled after the destination was created.

I edited the destination and upload the certificate. But the certificate seems not to be uploaded. The upload fields didn't change anything. If I check the Client TLS option, the upload field disappeare and I can't upload the certificate.

Is the only way to enable Client TLS option and upload the certificate creating a new one?

**[upload the certificate, but nothing changed]**
[image]
**[check the option, the upload field disappear]**
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Based on your screenshots, it does not looks like this is working correctly.

To enable client TLS & upload a cert, the checkbox needs to be checked and you need to upload the cert. If you cannot get this scenario, I believe if you upload the cert with the checkbox unchecked & update the destination, then update the destination with the checkbox checked, your cert should still be there.

Otherwise, you can use the REST API to upload your certificate after you have enabled client TLS on your destination.

I will look into the UI problem you are seeing.